# Uploading big files in PHP - file chunking

Tags: php, file, file-upload, ftp, chunking

I am supposed to write a system similar to Dropbox or Google Drive that'd allow sharing of uploaded files. What is the best way to upload a file of let's say 10 GB without leaking memory inside the browser? If I use a file chunking method, does the file get fully loaded inside the memory? (once you pick it for upload)

How do Dropbox and Google Drive handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this repo could help you https://github.com/flowjs

Comment: What I'm mainly interested is how do they get the binary representation of the file that's being uploaded in order to apply the binary diff algorithm ( so you do not have to upload the entire file if only 1-2 kb of data was changed )

Comment: Maybe there is some documentation about gihub LFS?
Yep - https://github.com/github/git-lfs

Comment: That's totally different from what I am trying to accomplish.